# Unwanted CSS Border Style (DataTables header)

Tags: css, datatables

My CSS skills are still lacking, so apologies ahead of time. I am working on a page using the DataTables jQuery plug-in. On the headers of my table, I have a border style I'm trying to remove.

I've over exaggerated the effect to make it obvious what I'm talking about...

Here's a picture of what it looks like now...
[image]

Here's what I want it to look like...
[image]

Here's the page in question...

https://darkjedi.org/club/FOX/members/mwo_stats.php

I'd like it to just be a flat, black, verticle line.

**EDIT**: Initially I mistook this for a shadow issue, I've since realized this is a border-style issue.

Comment: So you are trying to remove the gold underline? It's a border, not a shadow.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "shadow" here. There doesn't appear to be any shadow effects, only a black left/right border on the `th` and the gold bottom border. Can you clarify what you're trying to remove, please? Maybe use a photo editor to demonstrate the intended outcome

Comment: Have you tried `border: solid; border-color: #000000;` on the the CSS classes?

Comment: I updated the question to show a photoshopped image of what I want it to look like.

Comment: This would be super easy to resolve. Please edit your question and include the related php, css, and html code so we can identify where your mistake is. Linking to your page does not give us the information we need to help you.

Comment: The PHP code is irrelevant as it doesn't manipulate the CSS for this. I did not post the CSS because it is nearly 400 lines long (generated by DataTables theme creator at https://datatables.net/manual/styling/theme-creator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by:

- removing the right border
- making the `th` relatively positioned
- adding an absolutely positioned black bar and making it the width of the removed border (via `::after`)
- pinning the absolutely positioned black bar to the right of the cell, so it acts as a border
- adjusting the `background-position` of the sorting arrows so they're offset properly from the right cell wall

```css
table.dataTable.compact thead th {
  padding-right: 25px;
  border-right: none;
  position: relative;
}

table.dataTable.compact thead th::after {
  content: '';
  width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top:0;
}

table.dataTable thead .sorting,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc {
  background-position: calc(100% - 5px) 50% !important;
}
```

[image]

[image]